# Zip all files returned from "grep-ril" command

Tags: bash, grep, zip

I'm using `grep -ril` to be able to see all files that contain a certain string:

```
[user@machine]$ grep -ril "test string"
file1.log
file2.log
file3.log
file4.log
...
```

I then would like to zip all of the files that have been returned by that command. Is this possible?

I've tried things such as `grep -ril myPattern | zip files.zip` and `grep -ril myPattern | zip > files.zip` but nothing has worked so far.

Is there a workaround to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [zip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) command line switch  `-@` to have `zip` take the list of input files from standard input instead of from the command line. For example,

```
grep -ril "test string" | zip name-of-new-zip-file -@
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the command on this way:

```
zip zipfile.zip `grep -ril "test string"`
```

Comment: This suffers from the usual "any file with a space or starting with a dash" issue that makes it non generic, non stable and a generally bad habit to have as it can cause security issues in some cases.

Comment: @Ginnungagap, IMHO same for the answer of Bob

Comment: It probably suffers from newlines in filenames but it doesn't suffer from a file called `-o` (for example) being interpreted as a command line switch by `zip` nor does it suffer from `filename with space` (again, for example) being interpreted as 3 separate files. And as a general rule, it's better to pipe than to expand on the command line since it's unlikely to change the behavior of the invoked program.

Comment: Actually, looking for an document illustrating this, I stumbled upon [this](https://insinuator.net/2014/12/revisiting-an-old-friend-shell-globbing/) which explains the issue and actually lists `zip` as a security issue with this kind of invocation.